# How can I make a browser display a 'Save As' dialog when a button is clicked in an Angular application, ensuring it works on all browsers?

Tags: javascript, angular

[image: Window]

[image: mac]

And solution should work on Windows and mac, and also we can give default file name, and type also

Comment: What did you try so far? We need code in order to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
downloadFile(data: any, filename: string = 'default.csv') {
  const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'csv' });
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const anchorElement = document.createElement('a');
  anchorElement.href = url;
  anchorElement.setAttribute('download', filename);
  anchorElement.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(anchorElement);
  anchorElement.click();
  document.body.removeChild(anchorElement);
  URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}
```

to get pop up, you have to change your browser's settings (Ask where to save each file before downloading)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following example:

```
downloadFile(data: Response) {
   const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/csv' });
   const url= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
   window.open(url);
}
```

Another way is:

1 - Install dependencies for show save/open file pop-up

```
npm install file-saver --save
npm install -D @types/file-saver
```

2- Create a service with this function to receive the data

```
downloadFile(id): Observable<Blob> {
let options = new RequestOptions({responseType: 
   ResponseContentType.Blob });
   return this.http.get(this._baseUrl + '/' + id, options)
      .map(res => res.blob())
      .catch(this.handleError)
}
```

3- In the component parse the blob with 'file-saver'

```
import {saveAs as importedSaveAs} from "file-saver";

this.myService.downloadFile(this.id).subscribe(blob => {
    importedSaveAs(blob, this.fileName);
});
```

Comment: This solution is working but, It did not give the save as pop up window on screen so I can edit the name of the file, Thanks for your solution

Comment: The earlier solution also work
downloadFile(data: Response) {
   const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'text/csv' });
   const url= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
   window.open(url);
}
In the setting, I have to change the permission Ask where to save each file before downloading and that's it

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [showSaveFilePicker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showSaveFilePicker), but its browser [support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showSaveFilePicker#browser_compatibility) is very limited. It may work with Chrome/Edge in Windows & Mac, but won't work in mobile.

e.g. : The following code will download a text file with 'Save As' dialog box.

```
    const saveOptions = {
        excludeAcceptAllOption: false, 
        suggestedName: 'SuggestName.txt',
        types: [{
            accept: { "text/plain": [".txt"] },
            description: 'A plain text'
        }]
    };
    const newHandle = await window.showSaveFilePicker(saveOptions);
    const writableStream = await newHandle.createWritable();
    let blob = new Blob(['Hello, world!'], {type: 'text/plain'});
    await writableStream.write(blob);
    await writableStream.close();
```